# copying data from multiple table and insert into one?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to copy data from multiple table and insert into one table in same database. how can I do the same with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: You should really add some information about your data structure and the goal of your manipulation. The answer depends on a lot of factor.

Answer (score 1):

to be as general as your question, an example insert query:

```
insert into table3(col1, col2, col3, col4) select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2 from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.idColumn = t2.colID
```